# Keep NA values in their original position when reordering vector

Tags: r, permutation, shuffle

I have a large set of data that I want to reorder in groups of twelve using the `sample()` function in R to generate randomised data sets with which I can carry out a permutation test. However, this data has `NA` characters where data could not be collected and I would like them to stay in their respective original positions when the data is shuffled.

Currently, `NA`s are shuffled randomly with all other values. For example, where example.data is a made-up example set of 12 values:

```
example.data <- c(0.33, 0.12, NA, 0.25, 0.47, 0.83, 0.90, 0.64, NA, NA, 1.00, 0.42)

sample(example.data, replace = F, prob = NULL)

[1] 0.64  0.83  NA  0.33  0.47  0.90  0.25  NA  0.12  0.42  1.00  NA
```

Whereas a suitable reordering would be:

```
[1] 0.64  0.83  NA  0.33  0.47  0.90  0.25  0.12  NA  NA  0.42  1.00
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Thank you for your help!

### This has been solved, but I have an extending question

Extending from this, if I have a set of data with a length of 24 how would I go about re-ordering the first and second set of 12 values individually?

For example, a vector extending from the first example:

```
example.data <- c(0.33, 0.12, NA, 0.25, 0.47, 0.83, 0.90, 0.64, NA, NA, 1.00, 0.42, 0.73, NA, 0.56, 0.12, 1.0, 0.47, NA, 0.62, NA, 0.98, NA, 0.05)
```

Where `example.data[1:12]` and `example.data[13:24]` are shuffled separately within their own respective groups.

The code I am trying to work this solution into is as follows:

```
shuffle.data = function(input.data,nr,ns){
simdata <- input.data
  for(i in 1:nr){
    start.row <- (ns*(i-1))+1
    end.row   <- start.row + actual.length[i] - 1
    newdata = sample(input.data[start.row:end.row], size=actual.length[i], replace=F)
    simdata[start.row:end.row] <- newdata
  }
  return(simdata)}
```

Where input.data is the raw input data (`example.data`); `nr` is the number of groups (2), `ns` is the size of each sample (12); and `actual.length` is the length of each group exluding NAs stored in a vector (`actual.length <- c(9, 8)` in the example above).

Thank you again for your help!

Comment: One question per post, please. If you have a new question, post a new question. (You can of course link from this to the new one, and vice versa)

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
example.data[!is.na(example.data)] <- sample(example.data[!is.na(example.data)], replace = F, prob = NULL)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm after, thank you very much. I thought there would be a way to add an argument that would exclude the NA values in the re-ordering. I was trying sample(example.data[example.data !=NA]), which was obviously not the right way to go about things as it was returning a vector of 12 NAs.

Answer (score 1):

We can try with non-NA elements by creating an index

```
i1 <- which(!is.na(example.data))
example.data[i1] <- example.data[sample(i1)]
example.data
#[1] 0.25 0.64   NA 0.83 0.12 1.00 0.42 0.47   NA   NA 0.33 0.90
```

Comment: I tried Pauline's suggestion and that worked brilliantly, however this also works just as I was hoping. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: @Roald It is the same approach.  Only thing is that i posted 1 sec earlier or so

Comment: I did see that, I just wanted to let you know that I appreciated your advice as well and it did not go unseen.